Can't connect Flutter Webrtc to a Chrome Client
No matter what I do, I just can't seem to connect Flutter Webrtc to a Chrome client. I can confirm the ICE candidate and SDP were exchanged successfully.

I'm debugging with a Physical Android phone
I use it as the Wi-Fi hotspot for my PC
I'm running a Go socket server as the signaling server, all data
reaches the mobile client from the chrome client, and vice versa

What I did
I've been debugging this for weeks,
What could I be missing?
I've tried ordering and reordering how I create and send the offer, answer them, and when to send the ice candidate between the peers.
Steps:

call the MakeACallt method
It initializes the renderers
Then it creates a PeerConnection
After that, I register all my listeners
Then Got the User media (Audio)
Added them to the PeerConnection Track After
Add a socket listen to start listening for incoming Ice Candidates
Then I created a Peer Connection Offer
Which I then set as the local description
10.Once this was done, I sent it to the other client (peer)

On 2nd Client Side
1.They destructed the payload,
2. Extracted the SDP
3. Then Initialize their own Peerconnection
4. Set the received sdp as the remotedescription
5. After which they Created an answer,
6. And set it as their local description
7. Then the SDP (answer) was returned in a callback to the offerer
8. Who upon receiving it set it as their local description
While all of this was happening,
there's was a listener on each side, peers's connection icecandidate change, which emits the icecandidate changes to the other end as they come.
I can confirm that all data were sent and received on both sides successfully
But i keep getting:
RTCIceConnectionState.RTCIceConnectionStateFailed
I/flutter (31263): Connection state change: RTCPeerConnectionState.RTCPeerConnectionStateFailed

This is my Dart Client:


dart
import 'package:flutter_webrtc/flutter_webrtc.dart';

import '../core/services/socket_service.dart';
import 'enum/audio_call_event.dart';
import 'enum/audio_call_stage.dart';

class CallService {
  String? _remoteUserId;
  CallStage _callstage = CallStage.initial;
  bool shouldSendIceCandidate = false;
  List<RTCIceCandidate> _iceCandidates = [];

  MediaStream? _localStream;
  MediaStream? _remoteUserStream;
  final RTCVideoRenderer remoteRenderer = RTCVideoRenderer();

  RTCSessionDescription? _offer;
  RTCSessionDescription? _answer;

  RTCPeerConnection? userPeerConnection;

  Map<String, dynamic> _iceServerConfig = {
    'iceServers': [
      {
        'urls': [
          "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302",
          'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302',
          'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302',
          "stun:stun3.l.google.com:19302",
          "stun:stun4.l.google.com:19302",
        ]
      }
    ]
  };

  Map<String, dynamic> _voiceConstraints = {
    "mandatory": {
      "OfferToReceiveAudio": true,
      "OfferToReceiveVideo": false,
    },
    "optional": [],
  };

  final SocketService _socketService;

  CallService(this._socketService);

  CallStage get callstage => _callstage;

  Future<bool> makeACallTo(String userId) async {
    try {
      _remoteUserId = userId;
      await initializeRenderer();
      await startPeerConnection();
      _registerPeerConnectionListeners();
      await _getUserMedia();
      await _addlocalUserAudioTracksToPeerConnection();
      _listenForIncomingIceCandidate().listen((event) {
        print("got a new candidate");
      });
      _offer = await userPeerConnection?.createOffer(_voiceConstraints);
      await userPeerConnection?.setLocalDescription(_offer!);
      final response = await sendCallOfferToUser(userId, data: _offer!);
      if (response) {
        shouldSendIceCandidate = true;
        return response;
      }
      return response;
    } catch (e) {
      print("error making a call to: $userId");
      print(e.toString());
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  Future<void> initializeRenderer() async {
    try {
      await remoteRenderer.initialize();
    } catch (e) {
      print("error initializing local and remote renderer");
      print(e.toString());
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  Future<void> startPeerConnection() async {
    try {
      userPeerConnection ??= await createPeerConnection(_iceServerConfig);
      await userPeerConnection?.addTransceiver(
        kind: RTCRtpMediaType.RTCRtpMediaTypeAudio,
        init: RTCRtpTransceiverInit(
          direction: TransceiverDirection.RecvOnly,
        ),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print("error with starting peer connection");
      print(e.toString());
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  Future<void> _getUserMedia() async {
    try {
      _localStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        'audio': true,
        'video': false,
      });
      remoteRenderer.srcObject = await createLocalMediaStream("remote_key");
    } catch (e) {
      print("error getting user media");
      print(e.toString());
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  Future<bool> sendCallOfferToUser(
    String userId, {
    required RTCSessionDescription data,
  }) async {
    try {
      Map<String, dynamic> dataToBeSent = {
        "caller": _socketService.user.fullName,
        "callerId": _socketService.user.id,
        "recipientId": userId,
        "sdp": data.toMap(),
      };
      final response = _socketService.emitThisEvent(
        AudioServiceSocketEvents.makeCall.description,
        dataToBeSent,
      );
      final recievedData = await response.first;
      final recievedDataMap = recievedData.$1;
      print("printing response from call offer");
      // print(recievedDataMap);
      if (recievedDataMap["response"]) {
        final sdpAnswer = recievedDataMap["sdp"] as Map<String, dynamic>;
        _answer = RTCSessionDescription(sdpAnswer["sdp"], sdpAnswer["type"]);
        await userPeerConnection?.setRemoteDescription(_answer!);
        return true;
      } else {
        // await stopEverything();
        return false;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("error with sending offer for call");
      print(e.toString());
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  Future<bool> _sendIceCandidate(
    String userId,
    RTCIceCandidate iceCandidate,
  ) async {
    try {
      print("about to start sending ice candidates");
      final dataToBeSent = {
        "recipientId": userId,
        "candidate": iceCandidate.toMap(),
      };
      final result = _socketService.emitThisEvent(
        AudioServiceSocketEvents.sendIceCandidates.description,
        dataToBeSent,
      );
      final response = await result.first;
      final responseMap = response.$1;
      print("response from sending ice candidates:");
      if (responseMap["isReady"]) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    } catch (e) {
      print("error with sending ice candidates");
      print(e.toString());
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  Future _addlocalUserAudioTracksToPeerConnection() async {
    try {
      print("adding audio tracks to call");
      _localStream?.getAudioTracks().forEach((eachAudioTrack) {
        userPeerConnection?.addTrack(eachAudioTrack, _localStream!);
      });
      print("finished adding local user audio tracks to call");
    } catch (e) {
      print("error adding user audio to peer connection");
      print(e.toString());
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  Stream<void> _listenForIncomingIceCandidate() async* {
    try {
      _socketService
          .listenForThisEvent(
        AudioServiceSocketEvents.incomingIceCandidate.description,
      )
          .listen((event) async {
        print("got some ice candidate data");
        final payload = event.$1;
        final candidateData = payload["candidate"];
        final candidate = RTCIceCandidate(
          candidateData['candidate'],
          candidateData['sdpMid'],
          candidateData['sdpMLineIndex'],
        );
        await userPeerConnection!.addCandidate(candidate);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print("error listening for incomming call offer");
      print(e.toString());
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  void _registerPeerConnectionListeners() {
    print("registering events");
    userPeerConnection?.onIceGatheringState = (RTCIceGatheringState state) {
      print("ICE gathering state changed: $state");
    };
    userPeerConnection?.onConnectionState =
        (RTCPeerConnectionState state) async {
      print("Connection state change: $state");

      if (state == RTCPeerConnectionState.RTCPeerConnectionStateFailed) {
        await userPeerConnection?.restartIce();
      }
    };
    userPeerConnection?.onSignalingState = (RTCSignalingState state) {
      print("Signaling state change: $state");
    };

    userPeerConnection?.onIceConnectionState = (state) {
      print('iceConnectionState $state');
    };
    userPeerConnection?.onIceGatheringState = (RTCIceGatheringState state) {
      print('ICE connection state change: $state');
    };

    userPeerConnection?.onTrack = (RTCTrackEvent event) {
      print("got new track");
      event.streams[0].getAudioTracks().forEach((eachAudioTrack) {
        _remoteUserStream?.addTrack(eachAudioTrack);
        remoteRenderer.srcObject = event.streams[0];
        // remoteRenderer.muted = false;
      });
    };

    userPeerConnection?.onAddStream = (MediaStream stream) {
      print("Got new stream");
      _remoteUserStream = stream;
    };

    userPeerConnection?.onIceConnectionState =
        (RTCIceConnectionState state) async {
      print("on ice connection state: ");
      print(state);
    };

    userPeerConnection?.onRenegotiationNeeded = () {
      print("renegotiation needed, what are we going to do?");
    };

    userPeerConnection?.onIceCandidate = (candidate) async {
      print("on ice candidates ....");
      if (_remoteUserId == null) {
        print("remote user id is null");
        _iceCandidates.add(candidate);
      } else {
        if (_iceCandidates.isNotEmpty) {
          print("sending from buffererd list");
          _iceCandidates.forEach((eachCandidate) async {
            await _sendIceCandidate(_remoteUserId!, eachCandidate);
          });
          _iceCandidates = [];
        }
        await _sendIceCandidate(_remoteUserId!, candidate);
      }
    };
  }
}



and this is my JS Client


// Establish Socket.io connection
const socket = io("http://127.0.0.1:5000", {
    extraHeaders: {
        "User-Id": "ChromeClient"
    }
});

const recipientId = "Rider_Mike";
let callerId;
let localAudioStream;
let remoteStream;
let userPeerConnection;
let offer;
let answer;
let localCandidates = [];


const voiceConstraints = {
    "mandatory": {
        "OfferToReceiveAudio": true,
        "OfferToReceiveVideo": false,
    },
    "optional": [],
};

// Variables to hold local media stream and RTCPeerConnection

// socket to listen to incoming call
socket.on('call', handleIncomingCall);
// socket to listen to incoming ICE candidates
socket.on('incoming-ice-candidate', handleIncomingIceCandidate);

// function to handle incoming call
async function handleIncomingCall(data, callback) {
    try {
        if (!userPeerConnection) {
            console.log(data.callerId)
            callerId = data.callerId
            await createPeerConnection();
            registerListeners();
        }
        console.log(data)
        console.log("printing offer after data")
        await answerACall(data, callback)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }

}

// Function to handle ICE candidates from the other peer
async function handleIncomingIceCandidate(data, callbackFn) {
    console.log("receiving candidates", data.candidate)
    if (userPeerConnection) {
        try {
            await userPeerConnection.addIceCandidate(data.candidate);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error adding ice candidate:', error);
        }
    }

    await callbackFn(
        {
            "isReady": true,
            "candidates": localCandidates,
        }
    );

}

async function answerACall(data, callbackFn) {
    try {
        // Create answer
        // console.log(data.sdp)
        await userPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(data.sdp));
        const answer = await userPeerConnection.createAnswer(voiceConstraints);
        await userPeerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer);
        // console.log("printing answer")
        // console.log(answer)
        await callbackFn(
            {
                "response": true,
                "sdp": answer,
            }
        );
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

}

// Create PeerConnection and add event listeners
async function createPeerConnection() {

    try {
        const configuration = { iceServers: [{ urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' }] };
        userPeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);

        // // Add local audio stream to PeerConnection
        // if (localAudioStream) {
        //     // console.log("streams have been added")
        //     localAudioStream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
        //         userPeerConnection.addTrack(track, localAudioStream);
        //     });
        // }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("error creating peer connection, ", error)
    }
}

// Get user media (audio) and start call
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
    .then(stream => {
        localAudioStream = stream;
        const localAudioPlayer = document.getElementById('localAudio');
        localAudioPlayer.srcObject = stream;
        localAudioPlayer.autoplay = true;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error accessing user media:', error);
    });

// Function to initiate a call
function initiateCall() {
    if (!userPeerConnection) {
        createPeerConnection();
    }

    // Create offer
    userPeerConnection.createOffer()
        .then(offer => {
            userPeerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
            const dataToBeSent = {
                "caller": "Chrome User Actually",
                "recipientId": recipientId,
                "sdp": offer,
            };
            socket.emit("make-a-call", dataToBeSent, (callback) => {
                // callback();
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error creating offer:', error);
        });
}


function registerListeners() {
    try {
        userPeerConnection.onConnectionState = (state) => {
            console.log("Connection state change:", state);
        };
        // Listen for ICE candidates
        userPeerConnection.onicecandidate = async (event) => {
            console.log("sending ice candidates to the local candidate");
            if (event.candidate) {
                // Add the ICE candidate to the localCandidates array
                await sendIceCandidate(
                    callerId,
                    event.candidate,
                )
            }
        };

        // Set local audio stream to <audio> element
        userPeerConnection.ontrack = (event) => {
            console.log("Received remote stream");
            const remoteAudioPlayer = document.getElementById('remoteAudio');
            const localAudioPlayer = document.getElementById('localAudio');

            // console.log(event.streams)
            remoteAudioPlayer.srcObject = event.streams[0];
            localAudioPlayer.srcObject = event.streams[1];
            remoteAudioPlayer.autoplay = true;
        };


    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error registering RTC Listeners:', error);
    }
}

async function sendIceCandidate(
    userId,
    iceCandidate,
) {
    try {
        console.log("about to start sending ice candidates");
        const dataToBeSent = {
            "recipientId": userId,
            "candidate": iceCandidate,
        };
        socket.emit("send-ice-candidate", dataToBeSent, (callback) => {
            // 
        })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("error with sending ice candidates");
        console.log(e.toString());
        rethrow;
    }
}




Hi there! Please look at how to create a minimum reproducible example. If this is as simple as it gets, please highlight where things are last working correctly and where the error is coming from. What kind of debugging have you tried and already eliminated as the problem?

Are you saying you cannot edit your own question? If so, can you explain more here in the comments? This is a lot of code to go through not knowing what parts are working and which aren't.

Hi @rand'Chris, I believe I did that initially. But in the editing of my question, which was great, some translations were lost in between. But I have just put reedited my post showing what kind of debugging I've tried and what I've eliminated as the problem.

Signalling worked well, as both parties received the

SDP(offer and answer)
Ice candidates, and they were both added correctly

iceconnection and peerconnection fails regardless of the order I've tried
